# How to Create table in SQL with table level unique key with table level Identity Seed

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want a table where Column1 and column2 must be unique along with auto Identity on Column1:

Ex:

```
 Create table Foo (Id int, Name varchar(50));
```

Id column must be auto increment itself.

Data will passed like

```
A
A
B
B
```

Data to be inserted like below:

```
 1 A
 2 A
 1 B
 2 B
```

How can I achieve the same?

Comment: You don't want to do this.  Just use a `serial`/`identity`/`auto_increment` column.  It is not worth the effort to restart the count for every value of `Name`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree, if you have to take care of this yourself. When there's a built-in functionality, why not?

Comment: Can you please elaborate, I have tried it , but every insertion Column Id is increment to next number.. if I Insert A and B , I want Identity column remains same because column2 values are different. If the same values is being inserted then I want it to increase next number

Answer (score 1):

When you're using MySQL and can live with having a table with MyISAM engine, there's a built in functionality:

> For MyISAM tables, you can specify AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary
>   column in a multiple-column index. In this case, the generated value
>   for the AUTO_INCREMENT column is calculated as
>   MAX(auto_increment_column) + 1 WHERE prefix=given-prefix. This is
>   useful when you want to put data into ordered groups.
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE animals (
>     grp ENUM('fish','mammal','bird') NOT NULL,
>     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY (grp,id)
> ) ENGINE=MyISAM;
>
> INSERT INTO animals (grp,name) VALUES
>     ('mammal','dog'),('mammal','cat'),
>     ('bird','penguin'),('fish','lax'),('mammal','whale'),
>     ('bird','ostrich');
>
> SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY grp,id;
> ```
>
> Which returns:
>
> ```
> +--------+----+---------+
> | grp    | id | name    |
> +--------+----+---------+
> | fish   |  1 | lax     |
> | mammal |  1 | dog     |
> | mammal |  2 | cat     |
> | mammal |  3 | whale   |
> | bird   |  1 | penguin |
> | bird   |  2 | ostrich |
> +--------+----+---------+
> ```
>
> In this case (when the AUTO_INCREMENT column is part of a
>   multiple-column index), AUTO_INCREMENT values are reused if you delete
>   the row with the biggest AUTO_INCREMENT value in any group. This
>   happens even for MyISAM tables, for which AUTO_INCREMENT values
>   normally are not reused.

- [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Comment: Apologies , I'm using SQL server 2012, not familiar with MySQL.... I want same as above result but in SQL server2012. some of the built in functions of MySQL are present in SQL server 2012 :)